# How to display on HTML page load a function's return?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to display some information on an HTML web page when the viewer loads the web page. I have a function, called getID(email), that returns an integer. I know that this works, as I've tested with console and it works properly. My issue is being able to display the return of getID() onto the web page when the page loads.

I know that I have to use `document.getElementById('div id goes here').innerHTML('content goes here');` to change what a div says,  but for the life of me I can't get the actual information.

Here's what I have:

```
<div id='output'>

</div>

<script>
function showId() {
  var id = google.script.run.getId(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML(id);
</script>
```

I have no idea how to make this run when the HTML page is loaded. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the script on the bottom of the page and call the `showId` function:

```
<script>
  // you can define showId here
  showId();
</script>
```

If you can't put the script at the very end or you expect to be using other scripts and want to only execute after everything is loaded you can just wait for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMozilla_event_reference%2FDOMContentLoaded) event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   function showId() {
      // ...
   }
   showId();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, using the event listener really helped. I can use that to get something on the page automatically, however now my issue appears to be with this onSuccessHandler thing. I'm trying to use it to get the return from the function - which returns int id. The following does not work:

` google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showInfo).getLast();`

showInfo() simply sets the div to the value. This success handler is not actually getting the result from the function to get the id. Any ideas?

Comment: *sigh*. Fixed. A one letter typo was causing my hardship.